# Get subscriptions, feeds and article from google reader api for an user

Tags: api, feed, google-reader, subscriptions

I want to create a google reader application that for an user(google account)I need to get all its subscriptions, for each subscription all the feeds and for each feed all its items.

Please help me with some urls in order to create the post requests for grabbing this information.

Since the google reader api is not yet released I could not find any documentation for this. I have readed this article http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI but there is not specified how to get these.

I kindly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best PHP class written that I have seen and used. http://code.google.com/p/greader-library/source/browse/trunk/greader.class.php?r=3

Just add your username and password then call the function "listAll" that will list all the posts that are unread. You will need to write a few functions in order to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also found an android application that does the same thing- http://code.google.com/p/fast-reader/source/checkout